# Add an optional subexpression to a RE on python

Tags: python, html, findall

How I can add a subexpression of a regular expression in python?
Indicating that some html code may or may not appear in the text.
It's because I'm making an API for filmaffinity and want to make a RE to filter search results, but I have problems.

In the html code of a result there's an rating image, and in other code this isn't, then I would add to a subexpression to the RE, where the image appears, it can take rate for the movie (an integer), and if not, it returns an empty string.

For example, this is a section os resoults html:

```
<div class="mc-title"><a href="/es/film111111.html">Movie Name</a>  (2012)   <img src="/imgs/countries/CF.jpg" title="Country Name"></div>

    <img src="http://www.filmaffinity.com/imgs/ratings/8.png" border="0" alt="Notable" >        <div class="mc-director"><a href="/es/search.php?stype=director&amp;stext=Some+Director">Some Director</a></div>
```

In this other html code is not the img tag.

```
<div class="mc-title"><a href="/es/film000000.html">Another movie name</a>  (2015)   <img src="/imgs/countries/XY.jpg" title="Another Country"></div>

            <div class="mc-director"><a href="/es/search.php?stype=director&amp;stext=Another+Director">Another director</a></div>
```

So... I need a RE that return this:

```
>>>R=findall(expression, html_Code)
>>>print R
[('111111', 'Movie Name', '2012', '8', 'Some Director'), ('000000', 'Another Movie Name', '2015', '', 'Another director')]
```

Note that in the second tuple, there is not a rating... only a '' string.

My poor RE is this:

```
<div class="mc-title"><a href="/es/film(\d{6}).html">([^<]*)</a>\s*\((\d{4})\)\s*<img src="/imgs/countries/([A-Z]{2}).jpg" title="[^"]*"></div>\s*<img src="http://www.filmaffinity.com/imgs/ratings/(\d+).png" border="0" alt="\w*" ?>\s*<div class="mc-director"><a href="/es/search.php\?stype=director&amp;stext=[\w+]*">[^<]*</a></div>
```

Comment: Regular expressions to parse HTML? BAD IDEA (tm).

Answer (score 1):

For parsing HTML, I find [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) better than using straight regular expressions. There's also [PyQuery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery) which seems nice, but I've never used it.